# How much do the Castithans in Defiance resemble Elves?

Tags: defiance

If you have been watching Defiance, you could see that Castithans and the elves are physically alike.

But do they also share social and cultural similarities? 
Do they share the same values?

I would like to add this:

Considering that the rivals of the main Castithan family, the McCawley's, are a family of miners led by a short, bearded man, the whole "Elves vs. Dwarfs" dynamic is evident.

Comment: Considering that the rivals of the main Castithan family, the McCawley's, are a family of miners led by a short, bearded man, the whole "elf vs. dwarf" dynamic is evident.

Comment: To my knowledge, Defiance doesn't have elves. Which elves are you trying to compare against?

Comment: @phantom42 I meant 'Tolkien elves'.

By the way, please read the comment of AvnerShahar-Kashtan.

Comment: This seems a fairly subjective question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ignoring the slight physical resemblance, not at all.

Assuming we're basing the "elvish" characteristics of the race on the sorts of traits we see in common sources in [German and Norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf#Mythology) (or even in less canon sources like LOTR) then the [Castithans](http://en.defiance-wiki.com/wiki/Castithan#Religion) are clearly not elves;

1) **They aren't magical**. Pretty much every source agrees that Elves are magic users or at the least supernatural in originm

2) **Both genders are sexually promiscuous**. Again, most sources don't attribute extensive sexuality to female elves.

3) **Their religion is mono-theistic.** In ancient mythos, Elves were generally considered to sit alongside a pantheon of gods

4) **They're aliens.** Elves on the other hand are not considered to be alien but rather "other-worldly".

Answer (score 1):

What "elves" exactly?

Tolkien elves are of the earth, they are immortal, they don't have rituals about killing each other for mates, or torturing people who have violated community laws.  They aren't a culturally dominant member of a multi-species alliance who are fleeing a catastrophe in their home, and started a war against all of humanity to get room to settle.

I don't see the connection.

Comment: Please read the comment of AvnerShahar-Kashtan.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **probably**.
But the question is, which elves are they like?

Would you like to compare them to Tolkien's elves?
Norse elfs? 
German elfs? 
British elfs/brownies?
Rowling's elves? 
King's elves?
Cunningham's elves?
Dragonlance elves?
Dungeons & Dragons elves?
Salvatore's elves?
Warcraft's elves?
Santa's elves?
Norton's elves?
Zimmer's elves?
McNiell's elves?
Warhammer elves?
Reckoning's elves?
...

You get the idea. There is no single definition of "elf," so yeah, you can probably find someone who wrote elves a lot like Castithans.

Comment: In the comment he mentions that he means "tolkien elves". It doesn't improve the question but it does at least clarify it a little

Comment: In that case, I'd agree with the other answers. They bare only the most general and cursory similarities to Tolkien's elves... the same kinds of similarities they could draw with humans, or generally any other humanoid.

Comment: You left out Keebler Elves...

Comment: @Oldcat - He also left out the elves that keep you from hurting yourself"; "Elf & Safety"